# reason: '-[CNContact setSnapshot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc84c8491c0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

It crashed while I deleted a contacted from iPhone Contacts.
The code below,

```
CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
        CNContactFetchRequest * contactRequest = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:[self contactKeys]];
        [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:contactRequest error:&err usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            if([contact.familyName isEqualToString:contactItem.familyName] &&
               [contact.middleName isEqualToString:contactItem.middleName] &&
               [contact.givenName isEqualToString:contactItem.givenName]) {

                CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>* number1 = [contact.phoneNumbers firstObject];
                CNPhoneNumber *phone = number1.value;
                NSString *number2 = [contactItem.phoneNumbers firstObject];
                if ([phone.stringValue isEqualToString:number2]) {
                    CNSaveRequest *deleteRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
                    [deleteRequest deleteContact:(CNMutableContact *)contact];
                    CNContactStore *deletestore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
                    [deletestore executeSaveRequest:deleteRequest error:nil];
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }
        }];
```

When the thread is running here `[deletestore executeSaveRequest:deleteRequest error:nil];` , which got crashed!
I really don't understand what's wrong with the code~  It is a simple snippet.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Until now ,no one answer my question.
I have solved it by myself.
I get all person from Contacts and then iterate the person.
The solution is :
original code      `[deleteRequest deleteContact:(CNMutableContact *)contact];`
after changed code        `[deleteRequest deleteContact:(CNMutableContact *)contact mutableCopy];`

That's okay. But I don't know why?